# How to remove UIViewController transition animations?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

On my storyboard I have two view controllers, and I have a button transitioning to the second one using 'show'. I'm new to `viewControllers` and I want to know how to remove the transition animation.

Step by step answer preferred.

Comment: Please provide a code example, If your looking for a step by step tutorial then Google is a great resource, if you have a specific question or issue then provide the code where you are stuck.

Comment: so far the transition was only done through the storyboard, so there is no code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the arrow that connects the two view controllers:

[image]

so now on your right change the storyboard segue to **present modally** and deselect **animates**

[image]

I can not test now but it should work.